# Not able to see output

Tags: java

```
import java.io.FileInputStream; 

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;


public class Encode 
{



public static String encodeFileStream(String filePath) throws Exception //file path ex : C:\Program Files\Cordys\Web\reports\I0001180.pdf
{    

 StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();

try 
{


   FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(filePath);
   //StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();
   int lineLength = 72;
   byte[] buf = new byte[lineLength/4*3];


   while (true) 
   {
     int len = fin.read(buf);
     if (len <= 0)
    {
      break;
    }

    //new Base64().encode(byte);
    //sb.append(Base64.encode(buf));
    //sb.append(Base64.encodeBase64(buf));

    Base64 b = new Base64();
    sb.append(b.encode(buf)); 




   //return sb.toString();
  }
}  

 catch(Exception e) 
 {
   return e.getMessage();
 }

return sb.toString();
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
{

    try
    {

      String s="";

    s=encodeFileStream("E:/CSSDocument/Test.pdf");
    }

    catch(Exception e)
    {
            e.getMessage();
    }

}
}
```

Comment: @monika please cleanup your code.

Comment: In the future, please format your code (select it and press Ctrl+K, or press the '<>' button in the editor. Also please tell us what your problem is?

Comment: Please describe you problem in a few *words*.

Answer (score 1):

after the line

```
s=encodeFileStream("E:/CSSDocument/Test.pdf");
```

add

```
System.out.println(s);
```

and please clean your code :)

Answer (score 0):

One reason that you cannot see any output is that your program doesn't *write* any output.  The `main` method calls `encodeFileStream` to read and encode the file, assigns the result to the String variable `s` ... and then exits without outputting it.

Add `System.out.println(s);` (or something like that) to output the encoded file contents.

Other points:

- Your code is a mess.  Fix the whitespace and indentation.
- The method `encodeFileStream` is poorly named.  What it is doing is encoding a file's contents ... not the contents of a "file stream".
- Your buffer length is probably too small ... and PDF files are binary so the notion of a "line length" is meaningless.
- Hard-wiring a pathname into your code is ... probably not what is required.
- Your program will encode the last "buffer" of the file incorrectly (most of the time).  Hint: `len` can be values other than `0` and `buf.length`.